# Automated deployment of Gatsby site

Tags: gatsby

Can some please advise what is the proper deployment process for a Gatsby website? Once it is built what's next?

1) Is it safe just to overwrite the old version? But what happens during the process while the new version is being copied? Will the old one start to misbehave? Also, I can notice that Gatsby generates some guid looking file names ...does it generate those consistently ..if it does not (generates new ones every time) the website disk space will continue to grow

2) delete first the website clean with some sort of maintenance page shown to clients ..and then bring it back online

Please do not suggest any services/companies that do these deployments and hostings for you. I am interested in implement this process myself. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/deploying-and-hosting/

Comment: Thanks. But that only sort of describes a solution - the most basic answer is in IIS section of that page . My primary question is how to handle the "copy over" of a site. Is it safe to just copy over the existing content ? Will it break the site for a couple of seconds (as it is being copied). Will disk use continue to grow as your hash generated names keep changing...

Comment: Which provider are you using? Could you provide details on how it handles deployments?

Comment: I manage my own Apache driven deployment on a generic hosting. Nothing special about the hosting provider. I am responsible for my own deployments and would like to keep it that way. Just want to know how others in my shoes handle that. I am not interested in other services that work of various hooks and manage deployments for me. Thanks